# javascript push inside init method not updating array length correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, init

I'm trying to create an array of objects with an init method, and when I push an object into an array, it should push another object into the array, while keeping track of the length of the array.. The problem is that it doesn't update the length of the array until all the objects have been added, so when each object tries to grab the length, they all get 0.
How can I have it update the length in this process?
here's the jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bg3Vg/13/
As you can see it gives a message showing that the grouptotal is 5, but it seems as if the total counts up from the last pushed object to the first.. I need it to work in the correct order so that the last pushed object can retrieve the correct length.

```
var colorGroup = [];
var grouptotal = 0;

colorGroup.push(new groupdata(0) );
alert(grouptotal+","+colorGroup[colorGroup.length-1].parent);

function groupdata(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.refnum;

    this.init =  function() 
    {
        grouptotal++;
        this.refnum = colorGroup.length;
        if(grouptotal<5)colorGroup.push(new groupdata( this.refnum ) );
    }
    this.init();

}
```

edit:
ok, I found a way to solve my problem I think. Let me know how horrid this solution is..http://jsfiddle.net/EqAqv/1/

```
var colorGroup = [];
var grouptotal = 0;

var colorGroupWait = [];

colorGroup.push(new groupdata(0) );

while(colorGroupWait.length>0){
    var newcolorGroup = colorGroupWait.shift();

    colorGroup.push(new groupdata(newcolorGroup) );
}

alert(grouptotal+","+colorGroup[colorGroup.length-1].parent);  
alert(grouptotal+","+colorGroup[colorGroup.length-2].parent); 

function groupdata(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.refnum;

    this.init =  function() 
    {
        grouptotal++;
        this.refnum = colorGroup.length;
         if(colorGroup.length<5)colorGroupWait.unshift( this.refnum );
    }
    this.init();

}
```

Comment: Why do you try to reference `groupdata` instance by their `refnum` instead of simply by object reference?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I am trying to count how many objects have been set to push so that they reference the correct id in the array. I cant use a for loop though..

Comment: no, I rather was asking what for you need `refnum` at all? For example it would be much easier to pass an instance as the `parent` instead of some number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EthanBrown has already pointed out the problems. Here is a solution that puts all the logic in the constructor, and avoids the problem of pushing the instance after having it created from a wrong number.

```
function GroupData(parentnum) {
    this.parentnum = parentnum;

    this.refnum = GroupData.colorGroup.length;
    GroupData.colorGroup.push(this);

    if (GroupData.colorGroup.length < 5)
        new GroupData(this.refnum);
}
GroupData.colorGroup = [];

var root = new GroupData(0);
alert(GroupData.colorGroup.length+", "
     +GroupData.colorGroup[GroupData.colorGroup.length-1].parentnum);
```

Comment: This is interesting.. I'm having difficulty adapting my mind to the way it is structured. I edited my original post to show a solution that I have made myself.. You can tell me if it is bad practice.. I'll try to understand your solution though..

Comment: It just has moved the `push` inside the constructor, made `init` not an immediately-executed method but just put the code, put the array in the `GroupData` "namespace" to make it logically belonging there, and removed that `grouptotal` thing which was never more than an obscure alias for the array's length.

Comment: Yes, your solution is still horrid, even more than the first attempt. One does not understand what `colorGroupWait` is supposed to contain, how it does get filled (seems to happen in two places?) and why it is emptied again. Where does it belong to? Is it internal to `groupData`, or is it merely a helper to the code that creates the 5 instances? It's a mix of both, which is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript arrays *do* update the `length` property as soon as you push something on to them.  The problem is that you're recursively calling the constructor, so the statement `this.refnum = colorGroup.length` is getting executed for each initialization *BEFORE* any push occurs.

In other words, JavaScript is working as expected.

Is there any particular reason you are doing it in this convoluted manner?  It be more straightforward (and achieve the result you're looking for) if you just did it like this:

```
for(grouptotal=0; grouptotal<5; grouptotal++){
    colorGroup.push( new groupdata(grouptotal) );
}
```

Also, it is convention in JavaScript to name object constructors with a capital letter.  So, while `groupdata` is not invalid syntax, it is confusing: you should consider naming it `Groupdata`.

Comment: I need it the way I posted, because it may push more than one into the array for each new addition. I simplified the problem, but my scenario is more complex. So say, I add one.. it finds that it must add 4.. then for each of those, they add another based on what each of those decide, etc, etc.. I can't use a for loop, because each addition needs to reference the previous additions, but I won't be able to tell what they reference until it happens. If I keep a value and increment it, it wont stay in sync with everything else as far as I can tell..

Comment: If the logic ("*finds that it needs…*") needs to be inside the constructor, then you should not the one to be adding it. Instead, put all the logic about `refnums` and `colorGroups` (and whatever) *in the constructor*, and then *tell it* to create something. You should not need to push the item to the array yourself.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Bergi.  By and large, object constructors should follow the principle of self-concern: they should only be responsible for initializing the properties of a *single* object.  If a constructor needs to construct other objects, then that is an indication that you need something outside of it to manage those relationships.  If you need objects to have unique IDs, that's easy enough to do with either a UUID or a incrementing integer.